# How to iterate through array in order

Tags: java, arrays

I read a file.txt and get lines as `String[] line;`

I have class, for example,

```
public class Command {

    String commandName;
    String parameter;
    String result;
}
```

My `line` can have 1 element inside array or 2 elements, or frist and third.

So, how to correlate my `line` with my `MyClass`?

I can imagine only `if` statement for each element in array-like

```
if(line.length==1){
    command.setCommandName(line[0];
}
if(line.length==2){
    command.setCommandName(line[0]);
    command.setParameter(line[1]);
}
if(line.length==3){
    command.setCommandName(line[0]);
    command.setParameter(line[1]);
    command.setResult(line[2]);
}
```

After that I want to do `map` like

```
Map<String,Command> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(command.getCommandName(),command);
```

and afterwards in some future method ...

```
String result=map.get("some command").getResult();
```

Thus, If I have named fields I shouldn't remember which element in `String[]` what mean.

Comment: Can't you just use a `for` loop for that?

Comment: Well, you can use `if`. You can use `switch-case` and maybe just change `MyClass` to have 1 parameter of `String[]` instead 3 separate strings?

Comment: @OmriAttiya I cant change, because I have parametized fields.

Comment: @Dred What Omri is saying is my solution. Can't you implement that?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand, why I got downvote -_-

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why can't you just use a for loop? Here is an example(notice I changed the code, now you can pass the length of lines you read from the `.txt` file and pass it to your `myClass` object):

```
Command command = new Command();
command.setLines(lines);
```

And change your `Command` to:

```
class Command {
   private String[] lines = new String[3];

   public void setLines(String[] lines) {
        if (lines != null) {
           this.lines = lines;
        }
   }

   public String getName() {
       return lines[0];
   }

   public String getParameter() {
       if (lines.length >= 2) {
          return lines[1];
       }
   }

   public String getResult() {
       if (lines.length >= 3) {
          return lines[2];
       }
   }
}
```

Now when creating the map:

```
Map<String, Command> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(command.getName(), command);
```

Then you can also do:

```
String result = map.get("your_command").getResult();
```

Now you define the lines variable by the length of the lines you read from the `.txt` file. This fixes your problem with empty or more values. As you also wanted the name, you can just get the first value from the array as it's always going to be the name, according to your implementation. This gives you much-needed customizability and automatization.

Comment: It doesn't fit to me, because in future I need implement `MyClass` to `Map` and How should I call `line2` or `line3` if in my `String[] lines` only 1 element?

Comment: You don't need to call `line2` and `line3` as the loop cares for that. If you mean that your `line` variable changes length, you can a method in `myClass` where you define the length of `lines`.

Comment: I should call something like `Map<String,MyClass> map`, where `String` is `line` and `MyClass` now have only `line1` or all `line1-3`. And afterwards I want to call something like `String line10=map.get(line1).getLine3();`

Comment: That solution is bad, because I need to get my `String` from `array` instead of `String`. It is expensively, isn't it?

Comment: Thus, You show me solution which close to that what I show in my question. It seems to me bad solution

Comment: Your solution is way different and way worse. Making all the garbage code automated in your class is the way to go. I mean if you are talking about my `if` statements, you can remove that and it will still work.

Comment: No, I am looking for something like `line.next()` from `Iterator` for `String[]`. Does it have?

Comment: Well, you can try this: `Iterable<String> iterable = Arrays.asList(lines);`. Then `iterable.next()`.

Comment: thank you. that is what I am looking for :-) And, by the way, if you named getters, i shouldn't have setter with if, it could be only `public void setLine(String[] lines) {
this.lines=lines;
   }`

Comment: Oh yeah, right you could just pass the lines(edited my code). Also please upvote the answer :)